# Do multiple thread request share same singleton beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading

I have been trying to understand spring beans. As per my understanding, by default all beans are singleton and a singleton bean with lazy-init property set to true is created when it is first requested and singleton bean with lazy-init property set to false is created when the application context is created.

So, in an application, when a user request comes in ( where each request is a separate thread), do all these threads share the same singleton beans when requested within the program/class?

Comment: I'd be careful with this idea.  In some frameworks, beans can move from server to server (one "server" might actually be a cluster of servers).  In that case it might no longer be true that you have a single object that is literally being shared by all threads in a system.

Comment: @markspace Even in Spring, singleton beans are only singleton within the application context (instance). Scale 4 instances, you have 4 copies.

Comment: I thought as much.  I just wanted to make sure the OP was aware of all possibilities, just in case it affected their design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default (scope == 'singleton'), all threads will share the same singleton bean.  There are two other bean scopes, `session` and `request`, that may be what you're looking for.  The `request` scope creates a bean instance for a single HTTP request while `session` scope maintains a unique bean for each HTTP Session.

For a list and description of all of the Spring bean scopes, check out: [Spring bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the bean is created with default scope, the bean is shared across threads. However, another scope can be used to achieve the behaviour you mentioned.
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand this is to understand how `@Autowired` annotation works.
Or in other words to understand "[Spring Dependency Injection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dependency-injection)".

You said, "

> by default all beans are singleton

We use `@Autowired` when injecting one layer into another between two layers.

**If exemplify**: Suppose, I want to inject `UserService` `UserController`. `UserService` is a Singleton bean. Creates an instance from UserService and Stores its cache. When we want to inject this service with `@Autowired` annotation. This annotation ***brings the UserService stored in the cache***.

**In this way**, Even if we do this inject operation in many classes.`@Autowired` inject an instance of UserService with singleton bean instead of dealing with one UserService at each time. It saves us a big burden.
This is the fundamental working logic of Spring Singleton Bean.

*Also, [Spring Ioc Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) manages this whole process.*

[image]